# WSO2 API Manager - API Definition URL Mapping

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Here is a simplified ASP.NET Web API

```
public string Get() {
    return $"Received value: 1,2 in string Get()";
}

public string Get([FromUri] int id) {
    return $"Received value: {id} in Get(int id)";
}
```

How do I map these in WSO2 API Definition? I tried the below, but it does not seem to work.

[image: API Definition]

I get the below error

```
{"fault":{"code":900906,"message":"No matching resource found in the API for the given request","description":"Access failure for API: /api/1.0, version: 1.0 status: (900906) - No matching resource found in the API for the given request. Check the API documentation and add a proper REST resource path to the invocation URL"}}
```

I would like the url to invoke something like this

```
http://localhost:8280/api/Default
http://localhost:8280/api/Default?id=123
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define 2 resources for 2 cases. (i.e. for with and without query parameters)

[image]

In your URL, version is incorrect. It should be

```
http://localhost:8280/api/1.0.0 
http://localhost:8280/api/1.0.0?id=123
```

If the version is the default version, you can simply drop the version like this.

```
http://localhost:8280/api 
http://localhost:8280/api?id=123
```